# org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

Why am I getting this following exception in my hibernate application.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK2C47CFCAB95CF1D: EMP [ADDR_ID,ADDR_ZIP])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ADDRESS [ID_COL])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1714)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1637)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1350)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:920)
    ... 9 more
```

For my mapping

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDR_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDR_ZIP", referencedColumnName="ZIP")
})
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private AddressEntity addressEntity;
```

My AddressEntity looks as follows

```
public AddressEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_COL")
    private String item;

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String ID;

    @Column(name = "ZIP")
    private String ZIP;

    ...
    ...

}
```

JoinColumn need not to point to a primary key. But still the exception occurs

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the join column definition. You can only declare a mapping using key columns.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_COL", referencedColumnName="ID_COL")
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private AddressEntity addressEntity;
```

and

```
public AddressEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_COL")
    private String item;

    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String ID;

    @Column(name = "ZIP")
    private String ZIP;

    ...
}
```

where `ADDRESS_COL` has to be a foreign key column in your emp table which references `ID_COL` of your adress table.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mismatch in @Column of AddressEntity. I have corrected the same in my question. I have ADDR_ID & ADDR_ZIP in my table which is mapped to AddressEntity(ID,ZIP). AddressEntity has only one primary key (ID_COL).

Comment: Sorry, I confused many-to-one and one-to-many. Will edit my answer.

Comment: can mapping be done from non-key columns from tableA to non-key columns in tableB?

Comment: No, that is what I was trying to say. Only between a primary key and a foreign key column.

Comment: I have the above scenario working with jboss4.2 and hibernate 3.5. But above exception occurs only when I port my application to Jboss 7 and hibernate 4.2. Not sure any implementation have changed in hibernate 4.2

Comment: I've just seen this error, and this is when I'm trying to use tables/classes generated by Hibernate 3.5.6 with Hibernate 3.3.2.
Perhaps this is a lack of functionality with older versions of Hibernate :(